# .htacces redirection with wildcards

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have been tying to get the site redirection to work but I keep on getting an internal server error

Here is what I need if the url is not:

`domain1/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/van******`

or:

`domain1/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/truck*****`

then redirect domain2

`******` = means anything goes (wildcard)

domain1 = http://www2.mydomain.com

domain2 = http://www.mydomain.com

This is what I have at present but like I said it does not work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !domain1/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/van.*
RewriteCond !domain1/content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/truck.*
RewriteRule .* domain2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: is `domain1` a folder, of a domainname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www2.mydomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/van.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !content/newzealand/mpc/mpc_newzealand_website/en/home_mpc/truck.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Remove the `$1` from the last line if you only want them to be redirected to www.mydomain.com and not to any other page within it depending on the request.